# How to use SVN in Xcode 5.X and check a project into it

Tags: ios, svn

Previously I have used Xcode 4.X in that SVN is very easy to access but now i have upgrade my Xcode to 5.X. I am unable to understand how to check in a project. I have searched for this but for me none of it is clear can any one give me steps to check-in,checkout and see the projects in SVN ..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Source control menu of Xcode

[image]

And add your URL here to configure your svn repo

[image]

And here you can add your project 
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer can u please let me know how to push first project in to svn.I am able to modify the existing code and check in successfully

Comment: I have add the configure option for adding your project :)

Comment: Sorry i am unable to see the Option called Projects in the source control menu i am starting with Checkout if i have no check-out copies if i check out any project it shows me to configure that project only

Comment: The steps are for adding the file into SVN is checkout the SVN folder repo and add your files..